# Адаптивные иконки запуска приложений (Adaptive Icons)

Tags: android

Верно ли, что начиная с Android 8.0 (API level 26) требуется при разработке/создании иконок для приложений использовать `Adaptive Icons`? В чем заключаются особенности `Adaptive Icons`? Обязательно ли их использовать?

Answer (score 4):

> Верно ли, что начиная с Android 8.0 (API level 26) требуется при
>   разработке/создании иконок для приложений использовать `Adaptive Icons`?

[Действительно](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html), в Android 8.0 (API level 26) представлены адаптивные иконки для запуска приложений (`Adaptive Icons`), которые позволяют на различных устройствах отображать все иконки в единой, и, в тоже время, настраиваемой внешней форме.

> В чем заключаются особенности `Adaptive Icons`  ?

Особенность заключается в использовании двух слоев (`layers`), которые содержат `background` и `foreground`.  `Background` должен быть полностью непрозрачным, тогда как `foreground` может быть прозрачным.

[image]

В Android 7.1 (API level 25 и ниже) иконки запуска приложений соответствовали размерам 48x48 dp. Сейчас вы должны устанавливать размеры для ваших иконок используя следующие принципы (`guidelines`):

- Оба слоя должны соответствовать размерам 108x108 dp;
- Внутренние 72x72 dp будут включены в область просмотра накладываемую маской;
- Система резервирует 18 dp  с каждой из 4 сторон для создания некоторых визуальных эффектов.

Следует отметить, что анимированные визуальные эффекты генерируются поддерживающим это лаунчером (Launcher). Различные лаунчеры могут варьировать визуальные эффекты по своему.

Также различные устройства могут указывать маску, в которых длина радиуса может достигать минимум 33dp до определенных точек формы. То есть минимальный охват маской не должен обрезать область просмотра иконки радиусом в 66dp. (*Наглядно в картинках* [здесь](https://medium.com/google-design/designing-adaptive-icons-515af294c783))

> Обязательно ли их использовать ?

Если вы не обновите свою иконку запуска приложения с использованием необходимых слоев, то она не будет соответствовать другим иконкам отображаемым системным `UI` и не будет поддерживать визуальные эффекты.

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html)